# Problem about the ground state energy calculated with quantum Monte-Carlo

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, variational-principle, ground-state

There are many quantum Monte-Carlo methods. Many of them can be used to calculate or estimate the ground state energy.

The problem is, is the estimated energy an upper bound of the true ground state energy? We know an estimate based on a variational wave function has this nice property, but is it the case for the QMC methods?

Comment: Depends on the method, and what error you consider. Typical QMC has (i) a sampling error and (ii) samples the energy of a thermal state; the latter is clearly an upper bound.